# "Failed to register bundle identifier" error in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to publish my app on test fligh and i get two error.
one of the error;

Failed to register bundle identifier
The app identifier "my.bundle.id" cannot be registered to your development team because it is not available. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.

another error is;

No profiles for 'my.bundle.id' were found
Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'net.ekol.falevi'.

How can i solve these errors?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably have a wildcard identifier automatically created, already.  Delete it so that you can create a new one for the same identifier.

Comment: so I can delete the default identifier and add a new one so that the test flight won't be a problem, will it be like this?